# NodeJS Express - Want to run handler twice on single route

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, express

I have a route `router.get('/generateDoc', handleRequest);` and I want to run this handleRequest twice. Can someone suggest me how to tackle this situation.

Below is my code example.

```
function handleRequest(req, res, next) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cacheService.clean();
        PdfController.generatePDfs(req, res, next);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an odd thing to require, but you can do it:

```
function handleRequestInnards(req, res, next) {
  cacheService.clean();
  PdfController.generatePDfs(req, res, next);
}

function handleRequest(req, res, next) {
  handleRequestInnards(req, res, function() {
    handleRequestInnards(req, res, next);
  });
}
```

You would have more luck with a library like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com) where you can make this a promise and do stuff like:

```
function handleRequest(req, res, next) {
  Promise.all([
    handleRequest(req, res),
    handleRequest(req, res)
  ]).asCallback(next);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but can we identify when it trigger for second time

Comment: Maybe you'll have to set a variable in either `req` or `res` that you can inspect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also just add the middleware twice:

`router.get('/generateDoc', handleRequest, handleRequest);`